# Markdown escaping dollar signs isn't working in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I had to reinstall my Anaconda Python and it seems to be screwing up the use of Mathjax for some reason, ignoring my backslash-escaped dollar signs. The following raw content:

```
pears are \$8 million each, and apples are \$6 million.
```

turns into

[image]

How can I fix this or even debug it?

Comment: It works for me if I double-escape it. Like this: `pears are \\$8 million each, and apples are \\$6 million.`

Comment: I have to double-escape it now?! What changed?

Comment: Grrr. It's the implementation of `marked` in main.min.js that has changed.