# Not able to get $ symbol in a Jupyter Notebook markdown cell output github

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, markdown

I'm trying to use the dollar sign $ symbol in my Jupyter notebook in a markdown cell. I'm currently using \$ , but I've tried '$' and $ and none of them work. When I run the cell in my VSCode the output is correct, the $10 looks as it should be. But when I view the notebook on github it puts the text in italics and smooshes all the words together. I can't find anything on this. Please help! [This is what happens instead of the $ sign](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvp3F.png)

Comment: where's your code?

Comment: This looks like TeX "math mode", not Markdown. But your question really doesn't contain enough context for anyone to tell what exactly you are doing or what you should do differently. Please review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: I tried to link a picture to the markdown cell but it wouldn't let me. My markdown cell literally just looks like ``` The sum is \$10 dollars ```

Answer (score 1):

Text **bracketed** by dollar signs among a markdown text cell is a special symbol to trigger mathjax in Jupyter markdown. A single dollar sign is fine and doesn't need anything.

**Example that works in current JupyterLab**

This solution used in this example is highlighted here in the discussion of this post ['Escaping dollar sign in ipython notebook'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53228544/8508004).
Try something like the following with **double backslashes to escape triggering the typical dollar sign ability**:

```
This is a \\$10 test still \\$10 . Yay!
```

Or, if that isn't working, try single slashes as some seem say works. (I discuss this vagueness as to whether single or double more below.)

---

Because that example works in current JupyterLab (3.4.8 and 4.0.3), it should work in Jupyter Notebook 7 and forward as the current document-centric notebook is based on the JupyterLab tech components. (I haven't tested NbClassic and early versions of Notebook Version 6 today, yet I note the sources I cite below in the last section would have been using that back then.)

---

(Note, that Jupyter evolved from IPython Notebook when it added the ability to run other computational kernels, and so sometimes with searching for help on the basics of Jupyter you may want to also use, or keep your eyes open for, the term 'ipython notebook'.

A number of solutions are also reported on [this page entitled 'Is the dollar sign ($) used for markdown? If yes, then how can I safely insert it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/352941). Some of those say a single back slass but the one I linked to clearly says double backslash, and I think [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70484387/8508004) that around 2021 the the implementation of `marked` in `main.min.js` changed to not allow a single slash alone to escape it. ([This post](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyter-book/issues/750#issuecomment-653717252) makes me think the escaping working with a single slash only for a while was an oversight that got fixed so you need double backslash. Also see [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4244#issuecomment-928349563) for tests in Jupyter in various markdown context (that may now be outdated?).)

Comment: I forgot to add in the post that I had tried the \\$ as well and it still didn't format correctly. If I recall I think it ended up giving me '\$'. I'll look into these links though, thank you!

Comment: Hmmm... in fairly current JupyterLab (3.4.8 and 4.0.3), I'm seeing the escaping only being needed when you have two (or more presumably) dollar signs. This works in those two version: `This is a \\$10 test still \\$10 . Yay!` But you are saying it isn't working for yours? I suppose it could be a bug. In that case you'd need both the actual code text as text in a code block in the post and then the image or image(s). The only image you actually included in your post was not accompanied by what you typed so we cannot do the same and reply with images showing it working. ...

Comment: <continued> Plus, you will then need to specify exact versions of all the associated tech in your post, too. (I updated my answer with an example I am using.)

Answer (score 0):

GitHub uses $-signs in some places to start and end math-notation. To show the $-signs in such places as they are, you can try to use:
`<span>$</span>`